# Plot results from dist_tab() function from qdap library

Tags: r, ggplot2, qdap

I am interested in plotting the results from the following code which produces a frequency distribution table.  I would like to graph the Freq column as a bar with the cum.Freq as a line both sharing the interval column as the x-axis.

```
library("qdap")

x <- c(1,2,3,2,4,2,5,4,6,7,8,9)

dist_tab(x)
```

I have been able to get the bar chart built using ggplot, but I want to take it further with the cum.Freq added as a secondary axis.  I also want to add the percent and cum.percent values added as data labels.  Any help is appreciated.

```
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(dist_tab(x), aes(x=interval)) + geom_bar(aes(y=Freq))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question. Is this what you are looking for?

```
df <- dist_tab(x)
df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars="interval", measure.vars=c("Freq", "cum.Freq"))
#
ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=interval, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```